# How to load data using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am newbie to C # ASP.Net I use Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo that has connected to SQL Server 2012 but can not load data from SQL form. You can guide me to use SMO.dll
Thanks!

Comment: Post your code so far...

Comment: I using the Server and DatabaseCollection connected in SQL, but I don't know how to use the class in SMO.dll load data!

Comment: What exactly do you mean "load data"? Are you trying to view the data that is in there in VS? Or are you trying to load the data to use within an app your building in VS?

Comment: Most people use SMO to manipulate SQL Server (to typically do DDL or admin functionality) for which it is superb. Are you trying to insert or update data in tables? Are you trying to read data that will populate grids and/or drop down list boxes?

Comment: @MadMyche Ok. I'm trying to view the data with gridview in VS

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits I can't using the class in SMO SQL Server (DLL) to view the data

Comment: If you want to work with the db data directly, I would recommend just using SSMS

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found is to use an ORM named Dapper with one of its plugins Dapper.FastCRUD.

https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

https://github.com/MoonStorm/Dapper.FastCRUD

There are many different ORMs out there and Entity Framework comes with Visual Studio. They are all very similar in operation.

first you would create a model which directly maps to your table structure. If using Dapper alone you would create your query in a string or specify a stored procedure to execute. Depending on the type of operation the result would either be a bool or model. When executing the operation you would set a cast of the model for the ORM to recognize when sending data to the server and receiving. If you are using a plugin like FastCRUD, EasyCRUD or others the query would be automatically created for you and based upon the model and the type of CRUD operation would execute the appropriate query on the server.

This is oversimplified but there is good documentation o Dapper that will get you moving pretty quick. the documentation is lacking for FastCRUD IMO but EasyCRUD does have better documentation just not updated as often from what I can tell.